# How do I loop these two opacity functions in an interval?

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

My program: https://jsfiddle.net/60ucsfrb/

I am trying to copy the format of my change size function which manages to loop itself and continuously change the size of div with the help of intervals from an animate function. However, when I try to do the same format for my change opacity for the div, it does not work. Instead it only works once, making the opacity 0.9 from 1 and being done. I'm going to try a for loop instead, but I don't think I'm supposed to since the animate function is supposed to already loop it for me, but I'm not sure.

This is the change size function that WORKS and changes the div from 150 to 50.

```
function shrinkSize(elem){
    var currentWidth = parseInt(getTheStyle(elem.id,'width'))-2;
    elem.style.width=currentWidth+"px";

    if(parseInt(elem.style.width)==50){
        clearInterval(sizeTimer);
        sizeTimer = setInterval(function(){growSize(elem);},10);
    }
    
}

function growSize(elem){
        var currentWidth = parseInt(getTheStyle(elem.id,'width'))+2;
        elem.style.width=currentWidth+"px";
    
    if(parseInt(elem.style.width)==150){
        clearInterval(sizeTimer);
        sizeTimer = setInterval(function(){shrinkSize(elem);},10);
    }
}
```

This is the animate function that creates intervals for loops.

```
var moveTimer;
var sizeTimer;
var opacityTimer;
var mover = document.getElementById("movingElem");

    function Animate(elem){
        //only clears most recent interval, cant clear anything before that
        clearInterval(moveTimer);
        clearInterval(sizeTimer);
        clearInterval(opacityTimer);
        moveTimer = setInterval(function(){MoveRight(elem,'wrapper');}, 10);//a function that'll call another function after certain amount of time, speed of animation, once every ten milisecond
        sizeTimer = setInterval(function(){shrinkSize(elem);}, 10);
        opacityTimer = setInterval(function(){decreaseOpacity(elem);}, 10);
    
    }
```

And this is my NOT WORKING change opacity function that I'm trying to follow the same format as change size function.

```
function increaseOpacity(elem){
    var currentOpacity = parseInt(getTheStyle(elem.id,'opacity'))+0.1;
    elem.style.opacity= parseInt(currentOpacity);
    console.log(currentOpacity);

    if(parseInt(elem.style.opacity)==1){
        clearInterval(opacityTimer);
        opacityTimer = setInterval(function(){decreaseOpacity(elem);},10);
    }
}


function decreaseOpacity(elem){
    var currentOpacity = parseInt(getTheStyle(elem.id,'opacity'))-0.1;
    elem.style.opacity=currentOpacity;


    if(parseInt(elem.style.opacity)==0){
        clearInterval(opacityTimer);
        opacityTimer = setInterval(function(){increaseOpacity(elem);},10);
    }
}
```

I know it has to do with this opacity line not matching up with this pixel in change size, but I don't know how to get it working.

```
elem.style.opacity= parseInt(currentOpacity);
```

---

```
elem.style.width=currentWidth+"px";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use `parseInt` which parses the number to a rounded integer (in your case after the first shrink, it parses the opacity from '0.9' to 0). In the opacity case you are dealing with decimals, so you have to use `parseFloat` instead.

```
function increaseOpacity(elem){
    var currentOpacity = parseFloat(getTheStyle(elem.id,'opacity'))+0.1;
    elem.style.opacity= parseFloat(currentOpacity);
    console.log(currentOpacity);

    if(parseFloat(elem.style.opacity)==1){
        clearInterval(opacityTimer);
        opacityTimer = setInterval(function(){decreaseOpacity(elem);},10);
    }
}


function decreaseOpacity(elem){
    var currentOpacity = parseFloat(getTheStyle(elem.id,'opacity'))-0.1;
    elem.style.opacity=currentOpacity;
```